# Memory leaks showing up for tableview cells in the analyzer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an application which is working fine.But i need to be memory leaks free.So i decided to build with analyzer,then i saw so many small small memory management issues.I sorted out almost everything except this.here my cell object is shown as a leaked object,but really i don't know where i was wrong footed.this is my `cellforRowatIndexpath` method .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EventCellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:EventCellIdentifier];

        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_with_arrow.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];    

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; // Pre-iOS6 use UILineBreakModeWordWrap
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines =0; 
        [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];


    }


     [[cell viewWithTag:12] removeFromSuperview];
    [[cell viewWithTag:13] removeFromSuperview];

    PTPusherEvent *event = [eventsReceived objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];







    //cell.textLabel.text = event.name;
    // cell.detailTextLabel.text = [event.data description];

    NSDictionary *payload =event.data;
    NSLog(@"%@",payload);
    NSString *tes=[payload objectForKey:@"from"];
    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithString: @"From "];
    subtitle = [subtitle stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",tes];










    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;
    cell.textLabel.text = [payload objectForKey:@"message"];

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 



    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]]; 
    NSDate *todaysdate=[NSDate date];
    NSString *todaysdateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:todaysdate];
    [dateFormat release];

    CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(320, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font
                                          constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat requiredHeight = requiredSize.height;  


    MarqueeLabel *rateLabelOne =  [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, requiredHeight+15,155, 20) rate:50.0f andFadeLength:10.0f];    
    rateLabelOne.numberOfLines = 1;
    rateLabelOne.marqueeType = MLContinuous;
    rateLabelOne.opaque = NO;
    rateLabelOne.enabled = YES;
    rateLabelOne.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
    rateLabelOne.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    rateLabelOne.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    rateLabelOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    rateLabelOne.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.000];
    rateLabelOne.text = @"OFFline!cannot communicate now.....";

    MarqueeLabel *rateLabelTwo = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215, requiredHeight+15,100, 20) rate:50.0f andFadeLength:10.0f];
    rateLabelTwo.marqueeType = MLContinuous;
    rateLabelTwo.numberOfLines = 1;
    rateLabelTwo.opaque = NO;
    rateLabelTwo.enabled = YES;
    rateLabelTwo.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
    rateLabelTwo.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    rateLabelTwo.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    rateLabelTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    rateLabelTwo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.000];
    rateLabelTwo.text = todaysdateString;

    if([chatstatus isEqualToString:@"online"])
    {

        rateLabelTwo.tag=12;

        [cell addSubview:rateLabelTwo];
        [rateLabelTwo release];



    }
    else
    {
        rateLabelOne.tag=13;

        [cell addSubview:rateLabelOne];
        [rateLabelOne release];



    }


return cell;
}
```

Can anybody help me to find out where is that monster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put an `autorelease` as,

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:EventCellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Otherwise it will be leaked.

**Update:**

As mentioned by AppleDelegate,

`[rateLabelTwo release];` and `[rateLabelOne release];` also need to be moved out of the if condition so that it will be released in both `if` and `else` cases. Analyzer will detect this also as a leak.

Comment: i think autorelease is not needed because of that dequeee methode..thanks

Comment: It is needed when you first time allocate memory inside the if condition, cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:EventCellIdentifier] autorelease]; For dequeureuseidentifier method delegate method owns the object and you dont need to use autorelease. If you use that will be equivalent to double release and app will crash. So you need the autorelease only at this place.

Answer (score 2):

OK here's where the issue lies..

```
 if([chatstatus isEqualToString:@"online"])
    {

        rateLabelTwo.tag=12;

        [cell addSubview:rateLabelTwo];
        [rateLabelTwo release];



    }
    else
    {
        rateLabelOne.tag=13;

        [cell addSubview:rateLabelOne];
        [rateLabelOne release];



    }
```

In your code the `rateLabelOne` and `rateLabelTow` are released within an `if` loop.The static analyzer analyses it as a leak since it assumes there might be a case where the code doesnt run inside the `if` loop.Practically its not a leak.

Comment: That's true. I missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:EventCellIdentifier]autorelease];
```

This will remove your memory leak.

Comment: return [cell autorelease]; will crash when UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:EventCellIdentifier]; is called and cell is dequeued instead of allocated as a new object.

Comment: I think, it should not. If your cell object will have memory, only then you'll come down & [cell autorelease] will release that memory when needed. So it'll not crash.

Comment: I would suggest you to go through the memory management concepts. Alternatively you can try this out yourself also. Here is the link for memory management tutorial, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html  You should put release/autorelease only when you own the object. In this case the delegate owns it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If needed i'll read it again. Anyways till now it is not needed.

Comment: Well, not interested in an argument. Probably you can try this code yourself and check it if you are so confident and let us know, so that we can learn something new that way.

Comment: Again, I would like to say thanks for your suggestion. I got your point correctly..

Answer (score 0):

```
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:EventCellIdentifier]autoRelease];
```